# Identifying the current view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

How can I know which view is being interacted with in the UI for example if I click on different views how I can identify them as text fields/buttons/labels etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on any view onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) this method will give you the view in it's first parameter.
Check if this View v is instanceOf which class, as

```
if(v instanceOf TextView)
```

{
    This View is Text View
}

Comment: Can this be done without a listener ? for example can i intercept it from somewhere else for example from a touchevent or motionevent ?

Comment: Only touch listener can detect touch event, When view is touched Listener will pass you two parameters,
V and Event

v: The view the touch event has been dispatched to.
event: The MotionEvent object containing full information about the event.
So by this view you can check if the view is of some type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (view instanceof TextView)
{
 //do somth
}else if(view instanceof ImageView)
{
 //do somth
}
```

Comment: Where do i place this this if statment is View a global changing variable ?